Comparing two series expressions for $1/\zeta(s)$. What can be said about their complex roots?
The following two expressions involving the inverted Riemann $\zeta(s)$ functions are well known:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} \\
-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}
\end{align}
where $\mu(n) = $ the Möbius function and $\Lambda(n) = $ the von Mangoldt function. The RHS's only converge for $\Re(s) > 1$, the LHS's are valid everywhere except for the poles at the trivial and non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$.
I wondered at which point both become equal and this is when $\zeta'(s) + 1 = 0$. For $\Re(s) > 0$ this leads to two real zeros: $0.03811277761...$ and $1.970017855...$. However, there appear to be infinitely many complexs zeros in this domain that all seem to cluster around the line $\Re(s)=1$. Below is a plot (not showing the two real ones mentioned before):

Q: What could be the reason for why the complex zeros all stay relatively close to $\Re(s)=1$?

It is well known that in the strip $1/2<\sigma<1$ the derivative of zeta (or of any $L$ function) is strongly universal so for any complex number $c$ (including zero too) the solutions there of $\zeta(s) =c$ have real parts that are dense in $[1/2,1]$; note that zeta itself is only universal so the same result as above holds for any $c \ne 0$
